# How to install sikuli in Windows 7(32bit OS)?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am using sikuli for the first time. I have downloaded a jar file named `sikulisetup-1.1.0.jar`. On clicking this jar file, setup box is getting invoked consisting of pack1, pack2, pack3.
On selecting pack1 if I continue, many more jar files are getting downloaded.

Following is the steps provided in the internet:

Steps:

1. Download sikuli-setup.jar
2. Create folder C:\SikuliX
3. Copy sikuli-setup.jar to C:\SikuliX
4. Run sikuli-setup.jar. It creates runSetup.cmd
5. Double click on runSetup.cmd
6. Selection Pack1.

But after running sikulisetup-1.1.0.jar, no runSetup.cmd is getting created.

Please help.

Comment: Open the location in windows command prompt where your sikuli-setup.jar is located. i.e. in your case go to `C:\SikuliX`  and just type `runSetup.cmd` hit enter. It will now take you to further installation process.

Comment: Make sure you have `JDK's path` in environment variable.

Comment: But for executing the runSetup.cmd in command prompt that file should be present in that location right?.But runSetup.cmd is only present present.Only some jars are getting downloaded if we double  click on this sikulisetup-1.1.0.jar.

Comment: [SikuliSetup jar](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/156398998/sikuli-setup.jar). Hope you have downloaded from the same location.

Comment: try with .. right click -> open as administartor